# dynamic-spree-sitemaps installation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap

Hi I am using `rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3` and i am trying to install `dynamic-spree-sitemaps` with following code

```
script/extension install git://github.com/polomasta/dynamic-spree-sitemaps.git
mv vendor/extensions/dynamic-spree-sitemaps vendor/extensions/sitemaps
```

but it gives us

```
bash: script/extension: No such file or directory
```

please some one help me

Answer (score 0):

I have not install this gem but `script/extension install` is old Rails 2.x command syntax. Instead do something like this.

In you Gemfile add:

```
gem 'dynamic-spree-sitemaps', :git => 'git://github.com/polomasta/dynamic-spree-sitemaps.git'
```

Or with https version:

```
gem 'dynamic-spree-sitemaps', :git => 'https://github.com/polomasta/dynamic-spree-sitemaps'
```

And run `bundle install`

Other way of installing directly from github source is by using a gem called `specific_install`

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l <url to a github gem>
```

In this case:

`gem specific_install https://github.com/polomasta/dynamic-spree-sitemaps.git`

Comment: it gives us Could not find gem 'dynamic-spree-sitemaps (>= 0) ruby' in https://github.com/polomasta/dynamic-spree-sitemaps (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'dynamic-spree-sitemaps (>= 0) ruby' error

Comment: I have updated my answer for using a gem to do this. If it still doesn't work, you may want to check if the gem is compatible or the source git url is correct. In anycase `script/extension install` won't work with Rails 3.x